# play framework using slick JNDI

Tags: scala, playframework, jboss, slick

my application.conf

```
slick.dbs.muf.driver="com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver$"
slick.dbs.muf.db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
slick.dbs.muf.db.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
slick.dbs.muf.db.user=HR
slick.dbs.muf.db.password="hr"
slick.dbs.muf.db.connectionTestQuery="/*ping*/ select 1"


db.muf.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.muf.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
db.muf.username=HR
db.muf.password="hr"
db.muf.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
```

how to connect play framework using slick JNDI connection ??